# Sendgrid open tracking event webhook not firing after the email is opened

Tags: email, sendgrid

I am trying to track email "open" event on Sendgrid. I have enabled Open tracking in Tracking setting in my Sendgrid account. I have also enabled Event webhook under Mail settings->Event Settings and I have enabled event webhook for all the events.

When I send the email, I get the event webhook response for "processed" and "delivered" events but if I open the emails I don't get any webhook response. I tried opening the email in Outlook and in Gmail in chrome browser.

Is there anything else to be done that I am missing? Please help.

Below is the response I get for processed and delivered mails.

```
[
  {
    "OrderId": "5555",
    "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
    "event": "processed",
    "send_at": 0,
    "sg_event_id": "cHJvY2Vzc2VkLTE3NTE3NjIzLV9PbGs1ZWx4U1VHUUZSTUk3aVBlY0EtMA",
    "sg_message_id": "_Olk5elxSUGQFRMI7iPecA.filterdrecv-p3iad2-865cf6bb5-sddvl-18-5F560026-42.0",
    "smtp-id": "<_Olk5elxSUGQFRMI7iPecA@ismtpd0002p1lon1.sendgrid.net>",
    "timestamp": 1599471654
  },
  {
    "OrderId": "5555",
    "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
    "event": "delivered",
    "ip": "167.89.12.138",
    "response": "250 2.0.0 OK  1599471656 r7si5783789ejy.514 - gsmtp",
    "sg_event_id": "ZGVsaXZlcmVkLTAtMTc1MTc2MjMtX09sazVlbHhTVUdRRlJNSTdpUGVjQS0w",
    "sg_message_id": "_Olk5elxSUGQFRMI7iPecA.filterdrecv-p3iad2-865cf6bb5-sddvl-18-5F560026-42.0",
    "smtp-id": "<_Olk5elxSUGQFRMI7iPecA@ismtpd0002p1lon1.sendgrid.net>",
    "timestamp": 1599471656,
    "tls": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to do this?

Comment: I got the open email event also. By deafault some email clients like Outlook or Gmail does not open the images in the email. When you manually download the images using show images or download images the open event is updated in Sendgrid and it fires the open event webhook.

Comment: I see the open emails on the Sendgrid statistics page, but I don't get the webhook event.
but I do get a webhook event for "processed" and "delivered".
did you change something to get the open event?

Comment: One more caveat I'd like to throw out there is: open tracking is only available for HTML emails and not plain text emails.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check the settings
[image: sendgrid tracking settings]

Next, check your setting for engagement data
[image: have to check Opened]

Finally, check your mail clients are allowed to download images and have any extensions block ads or not
Sendgrid will add a transparent 1-pixel image at the bottom of email, if with any reason cannot load this picture, you won't receive opened event

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, you need to go to settings-> tracking and make sure open and click events are enabled.